# List of optimizations available in clang and llvm opt

Tags: gcc, g++, clang, llvm

It is possible to get the list of optimizers available in GCC/G++ with `gcc --help=optimizers`. The legal values and parameters range are also defined in `params.def`.
Is there such a command and `params.def` file available for clang too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1- For `Clang` use:

```
clang -OX -mllvm -debug-pass=Arguments foo.c
```

or

```
clang -OX -mllvm -debug-pass=Structure foo.c
```

where `X` can be `Os,O1,O2,O3 and O4` (-O4 is equivalent to -O3 except the fact that it performs LTO (link time optimization) when compiled object files from source files emit `LLVM IR` instead of object code)

You will have two sets of  `Pass Arguments` in which the first is the `global kernel` passes and the second is the `function pass`.

2- For `Opt` use:

```
llvm-as < /dev/null | opt -OX -disable-output -debug-pass=Arguments
```

where `X` can be `Os,O1,O2 and O3`

**Update as of LLVM-15x**:

Since the [new pass manager is set to be the default pass manager](https://blog.llvm.org/posts/2021-03-26-the-new-pass-manager/), the answer above only prints the `legacy pass manager` passes. In order to see the new pass manager passes with opt, try:

```
opt --print-passes   "Print available passes that can be specified in -passes=foo and exit"
```

or

```
llvm-as < /dev/null | opt -OX --print-pipeline-passes    "Print a '-passes' compatible string describing the pipeline (best-effort only)"
```

Comment: O4 is an alias for O3 for a few years now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Amir's answer, to see the differences, for example, between `-O1` and `-O2`:

```bash
# echo 'main(){}' > foo.c
# diff -uw <(clang -O0 -mllvm -debug-pass=Arguments foo.c 2>&1 | tr ' ' '\n' | sort) <(clang -O2 -mllvm -debug-pass=Arguments foo.c 2>&1 | tr ' ' '\n' | sort)
```

which produces a diff:

```
--- /dev/fd/63  2023-12-03 14:02:18.393064827 -0800
+++ /dev/fd/62  2023-12-03 14:02:18.394064877 -0800
@@ -1,22 +1,47 @@
 
 ^
 1
+-aa
+-aa
+-aa
 -amdgpu-isel
 and
 Arguments:
 -assumption-cache-tracker
 -atomic-expand
+-basic-aa
+-basic-aa
+-basic-aa
+-basic-aa
+-block-freq
... and many more
```

You might also want to add `| grep '^[+-]'` to ignore output context.

Strangely, there was no difference between `-O1` and `-O2`, so I'm not sure what that means since there is quite a bit of output from `-O0` to -`O2`

Comment: at `O0` there are pretty much no optimization passes applied to a code segment, except `always-inline` and `earlyCSE` and bunch of `lazyCallGraph` passes for the new PM. The main difference between `O1` and `O2` is the higher thresholds for many transformation passes such as `loopUnroll` and `functionInliner`, O2 being higher than O1. `loop-vectorize` is also less aggressive in O1 among other things.